# Parsing Json string retrieving all fields

Tags: java, android, json

I have been trying to parse json with volley , somehow i managed to extract some data but i am unable parse other fields . What i am trying do is checking which user role is doctor and store only that user to a1 arraylist

```
{"user1":{"password":"******","presence":{"lastSeen":1484695229773,"status":"online"},"role":"Patient"},"user2":{"password":"******","presence":{"lastSeen":1484695229773,"status":"offline"},"role":"Doctor"}}
```

here is my code :

```
   public class Users extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView usersList;
    TextView noUsersText;
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
    int totalUsers = 0;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    private Firebase mRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_users);

        usersList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.usersList);
        noUsersText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.noUsersText);


        pd = new ProgressDialog(Users.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();

        String url = "https://**********.firebaseio.com/users.json";

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String s) {
                doOnSuccess(s);
            }
        },new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                System.out.println("" + volleyError);
            }
        });

        RequestQueue rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Users.this);
        rQueue.add(request);

        usersList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                UserDetails.chatWith = al.get(position);
                startActivity(new Intent(Users.this, Chat.class));
            }
        });






    }//oncreate ends here




    public void doOnSuccess(String s){
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);

            Iterator i = obj.keys();
            String key = "";

            while(i.hasNext()){
                key = i.next().toString();

                if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                    al.add(key); /// here want to store only user with doctor role
//currently all users are displaying
                }

                totalUsers++;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(totalUsers <=1){
            noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al));
        }

        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

i am successfully getting the Root Object "user1" and "user2" but i want to extract all other fields as well

kindly tell how i have to change my code for all fields.

```
EDITED

 public void doOnSuccess(String s){
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(s);




            Iterator i = obj.keys();
            String key = "";

            while(i.hasNext()){
                key = i.next().toString();
                JSONObject singleUser = (JSONObject) obj.get(key);
                String role = singleUser.get("role").toString();

                if(!key.equals(UserDetails.username)) {
                    if (role.equals("Doctor")) {
                       // doctors.add(keys);
                        al.add(key);
                    }

                }

                totalUsers++;
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(totalUsers <=1){
            noUsersText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            noUsersText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            usersList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            usersList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al));
        }

        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make this a recursive method to get all the fields, but I am a little confused, what is this a1 array you have? Is this an array of user attributes?

Comment: a1 is the arraylist for storing user names then i assign these names to list adapter

Comment: can u provide any example of recursive method to obtain all fields

Comment: i want to store only those user in a1 arraylist whose role is doctor ?

Comment: Check my answer, see if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give all users with doctor role.

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(
                "sample.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        Set<String> keySet = jsonObject.keySet();
        List<String> doctors = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String keys : keySet) {
            JSONObject singleUser = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(keys);
            String role = singleUser.get("role").toString();
            if (role.equals("Doctor")) {
                doctors.add(keys);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Doctor users are --" + doctors);
```

Output -

> Doctor users are --[user2]

Comment: i tried this but list was empty i should update the post with complete class

Comment: @Addi - Is the Input Json Same as in Question???, it gives me desired output for it. Please verify and Mark as Answered if it answers your query.

Comment: yes json is similar to this only user have their names instead . i am trying wish me luck.

Comment: i am trying to do this in android, i am getting unable to resolve keyset()

Comment: Which json library are ypu using?.. i am using google-json library

Answer (score 1):

You get the values from the User Object as follows

```
JSONObject user = obj.getJSONObject("user1");
String role = user.getString("role");
JSONObject presence = user.getJSONObject("presence");
String status = presence.getString("status");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have embedded JSON objects that can be easily accessed by the JSON object method: (assuming 'userList' is your root JSONObject);

```
JSONObject user2 = userList.getJSONObject("user2");
```

These objects can then have their properties accessed via:

`String user2Password = user2.getString("password");`

Note the property 'presence' is also an embedded JSONObject, and so will have to be accessed with the JSONObject.getJSONObject() method.

So if you want to store these values in an ArrayList, simply create:

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> userArrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
```

... and then proceed to store values (probably iteratively) with:

`userArrayList.add(user2);`

Comment: the problem is i don't have static users , there can be many users and with their name , how will i know what is the user name for to pass here to get json Object >JSONObject user2 = userList.getJSONObject("user2");